# Linux motion user - run it as ssh key as pi to remote server

Tags: ssh, permissions, raspberry-pi, motion

This question is related to the [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112087/broadcast-or-send-machine-readable-code-to-ssh-clients) [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114080/run-linux-motion-app-as-user) questions I had earlier, about enabling Raspberry Pi to act as a motion sensor that will try to ssh into a more powerful server when it detects motion (the more power server will then do additional processing via a script). So here's what I did:

- On the Raspberry Pi, I installed Linux motion app
- I also used `ssh-keygen` on the Raspberry Pi and then using `ssh-copy-id` copies public keys to the more power server, so that the Raspberry Pi can `ssh` to the server without having to type in the password.
- On the `motion.conf` file, there's a line for `on_motion_detected` event for when the motion is detected by Raspberry Pi, on that line, I have something like:

  > ssh user@more.powerful.server '/exec/some/script/here'
- But the script on the more powerful server is never executed because the motion daemon is running as user 'motion', rather than the user (pi) that did the ssh-keygen that the remote server accepts. I know this because:
- If I change the `on_motion_detected` command to:

  > on_motion_detected echo hello_world | wall

  this command gets executed and I see it on all the terminals that are ssh'd into the Raspberry Pi
- Or, if instead of on the on_motion_detected line, I simply run `ssh user@more.power.server '/exec/some/script/here'` on the Raspberry Pi's command line (as user 'pi'), it also gets triggered by the server.

So the question is, how do tell the Raspberry Pi's operating system to 'use' the key of the 'pi' user when the 'motion' user tries to ssh into the more powerful server, in that `on_motion_detected` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is moving your ssh-keys from `pi` user to `motion` user.

(Assuming that your home user of `pi` and `motion` is `/home/pi` and `/home/motion`)

```
# mkdir /home/motion/.ssh/
# cp -a /home/pi/.ssh/* /home/motion/.ssh/
# chown -R motion /home/motion/.ssh/
```

#### Explanation:

If not specified, ssh command use key in `~/.ssh/id_*`, where `~/` is home directory of user who executed this command. So, if you run as motion user, `ssh` will try to use key in `/home/motion/.ssh/` instead key in `/home/pi/.ssh`

Answer (score 0):

When I ran Motion on my Raspberry Pi, I found the home directory for motion was

```
/var/lib/motion
```

I discovered this by enabling picture saves and running the command

```
on_picture_save echo $HOME >> /tmp/home.txt
```

in /etc/motion/motion.conf and examining the result.

Putting the .ssh files in /var/lib/motion/.ssh/ enabled the connection.